# How to get value from TemplateField in GridView using asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to retrieve the data entered into a Gridview Textbox, but I am getting no data from that. Here is my code:

in ASP

```
<asp:GridView ID="Add" runat="server">
    <Columns>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
               <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:CheckBox ID="cbox_Select" runat="server" />
               </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:BoundField DataField = "Name" HeaderText = "Fee Type" />
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
               <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and in C#,

```
for (int i = 0; i< n;i++)
{
      string a = ((TextBox)Add.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox")).Text;
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to loop through [GridViewRowCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrowcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and find the control.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in Add.Rows)
{
    var textbox = row.FindControl("TextBox") as TextBox;
    var a = textbox.Text;
}
```

### Demo

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="SubmitButton" 
    OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />
<asp:GridView ID="Add" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

public class SampleClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Add.DataSource = new List<SampleClass>()
        {
            new SampleClass {Id = 1, Text = "One"},
            new SampleClass {Id = 2, Text = "Two"},
        };
        Add.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in Add.Rows)
    {
        var textbox = row.FindControl("TextBox") as TextBox;
        var a = textbox.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Win but still I cant get value from the textbox

Comment: Same Button Click event only

Comment: textbox is null or textbox.Text is blank? Please make sure `!IsPostBack` is used when binding to GridView.

Comment: U were right!!!. I left one `!IsPostBack` and it caused the problem. Can u help me with a good article to look more on `!IsPostBack`

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting an error?

Try including a condition inside the For loop...

```
If(row.RowType == row.DataControlRowType.DataRow) {

//do something

}
```